# how to focus an input element using ng.model dynamically in angular js [Not at first]

Tags: angularjs, focus

In my application, I'm using form validation for many pages. If I want to focus on the invalid input element how to use without setting true or false in directive for every element.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" focus-me="isError"/>
```

In controller.js:

```
if(scope.username == "")
{
    scope.isError = true;
}
```

Instead of using like the above code, is there any way to focus using ng-model?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a blank ng-messages perhaps something like this, to trigger a method in your controller to set the focus:

```
<form name="vm.foo">
  <input type="text" ng-model="username" id="fooUsername" />

  <ul
    ng-messages="vm.foo.fooUsername.$error"
    ng-if="vm.validFormItem(vm.foo.fooUsername)">
    <li ng-messages-include="some/validation/partial.html">
  </ul>
</form>
```

Then the method inside your controller:

```
validFormItem(item) {
  const returnValue = false;
  // Do whatever checking you need in here to validate the form item
  // to change returnValue;

  // If it's false (not valid) then focus your form item here;
  if (!returnValue) {
    item.focus();
  }

  return returnValue;
}
```

I haven't tested this though.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$('[ng-model="username"]').focus();
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.